# Need to print a "print view" in an Infopath 2010 task form

Tags: infopath

I need to have a way to allow the users to print the "print view" that I have created on a task form in Infopath 2010. I created a button to change the view, but this also shows/prints the Workflow details among other things.  We can not use code on  the button.  We also need the ability to get back to the regular form once it has been printed so that we can submit and close out the workflow.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you have any suggestion where else I might look for the answer I would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Javascript as shown in the following article

- [SharePoint 2010 Infopath Print Button](http://arcemise.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/sharepoint-2010-infopath-print-button/)

Comment: @ZakirHC Please mark as answer if you issue is solved.