# Infopath Print preview from javascript

Tags: infopath

The InfoPath Ribbon has a 'Print Preview' button. When this button is clicked InfoPath pops up the print view for the current page that is selected from the print settings. Is there a way to add a button (either JavaScript or InfoPath ribbon button) to print the 'print view' that was set for the page without having to click on print preview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reference

http://arcemise.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/sharepoint-2010-infopath-print-button/#more-179

The similar question has been asked here:
[Need to print a "print view" in an Infopath 2010 task form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/need-to-print-a-print-view-in-an-infopath-2010-task-form)